# DateTime is rounded up to the next day using ExcelLibrary

Tags: excel, datetime, excellibrary

The datetime I'm writing to Excel always get rounded up to the next day:

```
workSheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell(DateTime.Now, new CellFormat(CellFormatType.DateTime, @"HH:mm:ss"));
```

In the output Excel file the cell gets this value: 29/09/2013  00:00:00

The DateTime.Now from this example is 28/09/2013 19:42:23

Comment: @pnuts Yes. I just tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the cell value as a string instead of as a DateTime:

```
 workSheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"HH:mm:ss:ff"),
                                  new CellFormat(CellFormatType.DateTime, @"HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ExcelLibrary Project Source Code, you can fix this by:

1. Go to SharedResource Class in this location: [Project Source Code folder]\Office\BinaryFileFormat folder
2. Change the EncodeDateTime function as below:

   ```
   public double EncodeDateTime(DateTime value)
   {
       double days = (value - BaseDate).Days;
       //if (days > 365) days++;
       return days;
   }
   ```
3. Pass the DataTime object to the Cell with the prefered format:

   ```
   worksheet.Cells[iIndex, j] = new Cell(((DateTime)cellValue), new CellFormat(CellFormatType.DateTime, @"dd/MM/yyyy"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date format from OLE Automation to the .net format by using DateTime.FromOADate.

```
If oCell.Format.FormatType = CellFormatType.Date OrElse oCell.Format.FormatType = CellFormatType.DateTime Then
 Dim d As Double = Double.Parse(oCell.Value)

 Debug.print(DateTime.FromOADate(d))

End If
```